# sequence of div is not displayed properly when sliding?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to slide the div one by one based on time interval. First full iteration it will displayed and hidden one by one properly. For the second iteration, it will displays three div instead of displaying two div. I not familiar with jquery and css and all. Kindly help me to slide the div one by one based on certain time interval. I have pasted my code below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var delayMe = 0;
  /*
  $('.container div').siblings().each( function() {
      delayMe += 800;
      $(this).delay(delayMe).slideUp(300);
   
  });
  */
  var divlength = $('.container').find('div');
  var i = 0;

  setTimeout(display, 3000);

  function display() {
    //alert(i);
    //alert(divlength[i].attr('class'));
    l = i;
    m = i + 1;
    n = i + 2;

    if (i == 2) {

      n = 0;
      //alert(i);
    }
    $(divlength[l]).css({
      "display": "none"
    });
    $(divlength[m]).css({
      "display": "block"
    });
    $(divlength[n]).css({
      "display": "block"
    });
    console.log(l + " " + m + " " + n + " " + i);
    if (i == 2) {
      i = 0;
    } else {
      i++;
    }

    //alert(i);
    //$(divlength[i+2]).css({"display":"block","margin-top":"100px"});

    setTimeout(display, 5000);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" style="width:500px;hight:500px; border:1px solid #CC6600; margin-top:200px;">

  <div class="div" style="height:100px; background:red; display:block;">
    <p>Hai</p>
  </div>
  <div class="div" style="height:100px; background:green; display:block;">
    <p>el</p>
  </div>
  <div class="div" style="height:100px; background:blue; display:none;">
    <p>bgdfnbd</p>
  </div>
  <div class="div" style="height:100px; background:yellow; display:none;">
    <p>gvd</p>
  </div>

</div>
<input id="btn" type="button" value="click me"></input>
```

Output:
Initially when screen loaded : Red  and green will be displayed
Iteration 0: green and blue
Iteration 1 : blue and yellow
iteration 2: Yellow and red. Here red is displayed before yellow. This is my problem. Due to this, once again when the iteration starts with 0, green, blue and yellow is displayed instead of red and green. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @parag bhayani, pls find the jsfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/kottarsakthi/Lwmheejq/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/paragbhyani/Lwmheejq/4/) answer your question

```
  function display() {
    var container = $('.container');
    var divs = $('.container').find('div');
    divs.css({
        "display": "none"
    });

    $(divs[1]).css({
        "display": "block"
    });

    $(divs[2]).css({
        "display": "block"
    });

    $(divs[0]).appendTo(container);


    setTimeout(display, 5000);
  }
```

Comment: This is what i am expected. Thank you very much.